# How to set view size / PreferredLaunchViewSize Error CS1061

Tags: c#, blend

I'm trying to build a universal windows app with Blend for Visual Studio and force the screen size.

The following code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(480, 800);
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
}
```

Gives me:

> Error CS0117  'ApplicationView' does not contain a definition for
>   'PreferredLaunchViewSize'

How can I fix that and what is the best way to force the view size on desktop computers?
Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Which SDK version do you have?

Comment: latest i'd say? can't have a look now. but yes, latest

Comment: Cause if the app was created for SDK say version 240 it might complain about that. Otherwise would be great if you share the sample and I'll help